# How to sort the list based on student's last name using lambda in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting, lambda

I have a list with student names

```
students = ["Merol B Joseph", "Ferzil Babu", "Basil Abraham", "Kiran Baby", "Ziya sofia"]
```

I am trying to sort the list using **lambda expression**.

I want to sort the list based on **student's last name**

I just tried like this

```
student_last_name_alpha_order = students.sort(key=lambda name: name.split(" ")[-1].lower())
```

then I print student_last_name_alpha_order , but **it returns None**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `sort()` is a method which sorts the list in-place and returns `None`.

```
students = ["Merol B Joseph", "Ferzil Babu", "Basil Abraham", "Kiran Baby", "Ziya sofia"]
students.sort(key=lambda name: name.split(" ")[-1].lower())
print students
```

Will print:

```
['Basil Abraham', 'Ferzil Babu', 'Kiran Baby', 'Merol B Joseph', 'Ziya sofia']
```

You can use `sorted()` which is a function *returning* a sorted version of its input without changing the original:

```
students = ["Merol B Joseph", "Ferzil Babu", "Basil Abraham", "Kiran Baby", "Ziya sofia"]
x = sorted(students, key=lambda name: name.split(" ")[-1].lower())
print x
print students
```

prints:

```
['Basil Abraham', 'Ferzil Babu', 'Kiran Baby', 'Merol B Joseph', 'Ziya sofia']
['Merol B Joseph', 'Ferzil Babu', 'Basil Abraham', 'Kiran Baby', 'Ziya sofia']
```

But this creates a new list, needs twice the amount of memory and also takes longer because everything needs to be copied.  So it's up to you to decide if you really need this.  The in-place sorting is more efficient and maybe more error-prone.

Comment: :Thanks for postng the answer, it works perfectly.You really explaining  sort() and sorted() clearly.

Answer (score 0):

students.sort sorts the students list and returns the sorted list back to students. `Print students` , it will print out the sorted list.